# using ultrasonic sonar and mist maker together

Tags: arduino, ultrasound, sonar

I have made a cold steam bucket (ultrasonic mist maker). now i want to add automatic water level indication system for it using ultrasonic sonar module. i want to know if both mist maker ultrasonic and sonar are working at the same time, would the mist maker affect the sonar precision? I mean they both make ultrasound waves right? is it possible that when sonar is waiting for response, the mist maker affect it before the sent wave came back to sonar?

Comment: Looks more like a physics questions to me. Any way you could operate them exclusive: stop the mist maker and measure the water level e.g. once a minute. Should take no longer then a few milliseconds.

Comment: The frequencies should be checked, if they are well spaced they might cohabit without damage but functionality may suffer.  I second @Oldfart's suggestion to switch off occasionally to check level with mister off. The misters do generate a significant amount of energy and I would at least make sure the level sensor is placed in an acoustically insulated tube remote from the mister.